# How to fix an offline Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord

I have been trying to learn how to make commands in discord using python. When ever I run my code i get a message that tells me the bot is ready, but it never appears online. yes I have a .env file with the token.
`

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')


intents = discord.Intents.default()
Bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
intents.message_content = True

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")
@commands.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")

Bot.add_command(test)
Bot.run(TOKEN)
```

`

I have tried most everything, I gave the bot all the permissions it needs, and added it to the server.

The issue from what I can see is the fact that its not online, not that the command is invalid, maybe im wrong though.

Comment: Please include the error message and traceback that you are getting.

Comment: There is no error, its the fact that the bot dosent go online is what im trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple errors in your code. Let's go through them step by step:

1. Import the Intents before declaring your `bot` variable:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = ...
```

2. If you want to use commands, rather use the `commands.Bot` decorator:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

*Please note that you may choose your own prefix here!*

3. Don't use `@commands.command()`, it's meant for commands in a `Cog`. Rather use `bot.command(...)`:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")
```

4. `Bot.add_command(test)` is not needed at all here, you can get rid of it

**Your new code:**

```py
# All your imports
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("test")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```